# How to change system property using command line option

Tags: java, command-line

I start my java program(Test.java) like this:

```
java -DMyParam=2  Test
```

I can change this in code using System.setProperty() but is there any command line tool to change value of MyParam property ?

I tried using VM.set_flag but getting below error, probably because set_flag can set flags not system properties.

```
XXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 11441 VM.set_flag MyParam 1
11441:
flag MyParam does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible.

You might be able to change some manageable JVM flags using jinfo (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jinfo.html) but that command is also experimental and maybe no longer supported in next releases according to Oracle.

Comment: Better way of setting vm flag IMO would be jcmd VM.set_flag,e.g. "jcmd 11441 VM.set_flag MinHeapFreeRatio 45"

Comment: Yah! jinfo seems to be deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

No, don't think that is possible. If this is the way you want to go, you would probably have to expose that functionality yourself. Perhaps creating a JMX bean and calling it with [jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/)?